# using variable outside of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I will start by saying that i am really trying to learn node but having some difficulties. I am building a super simple Weather App that calls an API and then i want to return the data.

But i am not sure why it wont return this data to the console?

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{API KEY}/42.47994,-83.13040', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      //var info = JSON.parse(body);
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
      var summary = jsonObject.currently.summary;
      var temp = jsonObject.currently.temperature;
      var realFeel = jsonObject.currently.apparentTemperature;
      var summary2 = jsonObject.hourly.summary;
      var max = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMax;
      var min = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMin;
    }
})
console.log('Todays forecast ' + summary2 + ' With a current Tempature of ' + temp + '. But feels like ' +realFeel + ' With a high of '+max+' and a low of '+min);
```

Comment: maybe you should take 10 minutes to learn javascript basics before starting straight with NODE? it would surely be helpful...or in other words, wtf.

Comment: You should maybe avoid learning node if you don't have a good grasp of Javascript first, even though it's a simple language.

Comment: You need to learn a lot about asynchronous callbacks before you even start with node.  You can ONLY use the result of an asynchronous callback IN the callback itself.  You cannot stuff the result into a global variable and try to avoid using asynchronous coding techniques because only in the callback itself is the timing right for you to use the result.

Comment: @Travis Can you please update the title of your question?  This is way too generic.

Comment: this question was answered like million times on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your variables are local to the callback function. Move your console.log statement into the function.

If you want all your variables to be global (bad idea), remove the `var` statements from the callback function:

```
(function (){ // add this line
  var request = require('request');
  var summary, temp, realFeel, summary2, max, min;

  request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{API KEY}/42.47994,-83.13040', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      //var info = JSON.parse(body);
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
      summary = jsonObject.currently.summary;
      temp = jsonObject.currently.temperature;
      realFeel = jsonObject.currently.apparentTemperature;
      summary2 = jsonObject.hourly.summary;
      max = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMax;
      min = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMin;

      console.log('Todays forecast ' + summary2 + ' With a current Tempature of ' + temp + '. But feels like ' +realFeel + ' With a high of '+max+' and a low of '+min);
    }
  });
}()); // and this line to avoid global variables
```

But then you still need to have a piece of code to display your weather summary. The console.log outside of the callback function in your post will run before the data comes back from the forecast service. In short, you MUST put the console.log inside the callback function.

This answer directly is a straight reply to your specific question. Please understand that creating [global variables is an anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: how could i use those variables outside of the function.

Comment: As i am learning, why is it a bad idea to have those as global variables? Also tried your edit code and it is outputting undefined in the console.

Comment: It's because the console.log runs before you get the data from the forecast service!

Comment: Gotcha the idea of this is for something a bit bigger than this

Comment: @Travis - Trying to use variables outside of an async handler is horrible advice.  You can't control the timing of those variables and in a server environment, you can have multiple requests in flight at once which will make this technique completely unpredictable and error prone.  This is just the WRONG way to program for async responses and doing so will just create bugs.  The fact that the OP accepted this answer probably means they are headed down a bad path.  This answer is NEVER the recommended way to program for async responses and should be downvoted.

Comment: i agree with you jfriend00. I answered his specific question and did state that it's a bad idea.

Comment: @sebnukem - I feel like it is our responsibility to the community to not just answer a bad question with bad advice, but rather to straighten out the OP and point them in the right direction.  As it is, it appears that the OP has taken your advice and is now trying to make really a really buggy approach work.  Even worse, someone else might find this answer and try to use it too.

Comment: @jfriend again, I agree with you and it's been done. The question is about "using a variable outside a function" and the OP WANTS global variables: he's been answered correctly, and warned about his wrong ways. Advice has been given, and OP is free to do what he or she wants.

Answer (score 3):

Node is an asynchronous server.  When you execute a request that is going to block, the node engine continues executing the following code.  You're passing the request module a callback, but your console.log is being executed immediately after the request is fired off and before and results have returned.

What you want to do is put your code where you use the data inside the callback function.

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{API KEY}/42.47994,-83.13040', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      //var info = JSON.parse(body);
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
      var summary = jsonObject.currently.summary;
      var temp = jsonObject.currently.temperature;
      var realFeel = jsonObject.currently.apparentTemperature;
      var summary2 = jsonObject.hourly.summary;
      var max = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMax;
      var min = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMin;
      console.log('Todays forecast ' + summary2 + ' With a current Tempature of ' + temp + '. But feels like ' +realFeel + ' With a high of '+max+' and a low of '+min);
    }
})
```

You should also not ignore errors.

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{API KEY}/42.47994,-83.13040', function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (response.statusCode != 200) return console.log('Invalid status code: '+response.statusCode)                     
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);
    var summary = jsonObject.currently.summary;
    var temp = jsonObject.currently.temperature;
    var realFeel = jsonObject.currently.apparentTemperature;
    var summary2 = jsonObject.hourly.summary;
    var max = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMax;
    var min = jsonObject.daily.data[0].temperatureMin;
    console.log('Todays forecast ' + summary2 + ' With a current Tempature of ' + temp + '. But feels like ' +realFeel + ' With a high of '+max+' and a low of '+min);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you declare a variable with `var` you are declaring it to be scoped to the function you are in. If you use a name without declaring it with var it will look them up in the global "window" scope.

Drop the var keywords in the callback function and the function should mutate the global scope.